# I have an issue with the width of my exp bar

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to calculate the Width of my experience bar as i gain experience, but for some reason, it just stays invisible unless i manually in the code change the Width to another value.

```
var xpBarLength : float;

function Update () {
xpBarLength = ((playerScript.curXp / playerScript.maxXp) * 100);
}

function OnGUI () {
GUI.DrawTexture(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 225, 840, xpBarLength, 10), XpBarTexture);
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction it'd be a great help :)

Comment: What values are you using and what values have you tried manually? Is it really invisible, or just small?

Comment: I've tried changing the "var xpBarLength : float;" to "...float = x". It seems to be invisible, but i think it's just because the Width is = 0 for some reason :P

EDIT: It shows up if i, in the update function, change xpBarLength to a number instead of the calculation. but then i can't have it change in size.

Comment: What pops to mind is integer division. Try something like `((playerScript.curXp / (float)playerScript.maxXp) * 100);` assuming that's how you typecast.

Comment: Ah, good guess @William'MindWorX'Mariager.

Comment: Sure you can. But the result gets truncated. Take for example `(50 / 100) * 100`. `50 / 100` is `0.5`. Which is truncated to `0`. Then `0 * 100` is `0`.

Comment: So you're saying curXp and maxXp are integers @casper?

Comment: yes they were, i changed all required variables to float, and it Works just fine :) Thank you all.
I learned something new :D